# Where is HttpResponseFilter class in V4+ ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm upgrading some projects and i'm stuck with this one. It seems none of the nuget packages reference this class which used to be found in ServiceStack.Common.Web.

In fact I can't find it when searching GitHub so I guess it is deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HttpResponseFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.Common/Web/HttpResponseFilter.cs) was renamed to [ContentTypes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/ContentTypes.cs) and its `IContentTypeFilter` is now named `IContentTypes`.